# Azure AD B2C custom policy to enable/disable MFA

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

My team would like to implement the following case in our Azure AD B2C - we want to disable MFA for some of our users (it is less than 1% of users). As I understand there is only one way to do this is to write a custom policy.

I started checking how I can develop a custom policy and realized that I want to have everything that is present in "User Flow" which we use for the Sign In/Sign Up process (created in Azure AD B2C User Flows). I want to do the following to implement the new requirement:

1. Download Sign In/Sign Up User flow as an XML file
2. Create a new custom policy which is a copy of XML from the previous step. It is needed to have the same steps as we have in generated by Azure User Flow
3. Add new Orchestration Step that checks a parameter (which shows that MFA is enabled or disabled)

I have no ideas if this plan will work, but I started working on step 2 and I see the following problem, the XML generated by Azure references on some technical profiles that I cannot find in Azure:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
    <ClaimsExchanges>
        <ClaimsExchange Id="COMP" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="OIDC-V1-COMP-8d80cbaa-f07e-40d5-bd88- 
        50e9264d67a5"/>
    </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Could you please advise me on how I can find these technical profiles? 
If it does not work, how I can create a custom policy that does the same things as Azure User Flow? 
Maybe you know how I can implement given requirements without custom policies - I will be happy to get any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack", can find it [here](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-custom-policy-starterpack). Clone it and customise as you required. Here is an article that shows how to work on this starter pack, [Get started with custom policies in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-get-started-custom?tabs=applications)

Note: 
For disabling MFA for specific user you can use preconditions for the MFA Orchestration step.

Comment: Yeah, we want to use preconditions for sure. But I am afraid that default User Flow has many MFA specific steps and configs (if we turn MFA on for the User Flow). The default starter pack does not have them for Local accounts as I  understand.

Comment: Please have a look at this, it will hep you to create a MFA profile, [MFA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/multi-factor-auth-technical-profile)

Comment: Have a look at this sample to give you ideas on how to do this. https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/blob/master/policies/mfa-absolute-timeout-and-ip-change-trigger